# Multiple class from generic and modular styles

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

Let say i have two different style source, one from bulma.sass and the other from module.scss

this is the code

```js
import React from 'react' 
import { Link } from 'gatsby' 
import HeaderStyles from './header.module.scss'
import '../styles/bulma.sass'

const Header = () => {
  return (
     <Link className={HeaderStyles.link} to="/">Home</Link>
  )
}
```

In this case i need to add other class from bulma. So my question is how to add the other class into the `Link` element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both styles asserts to regular css classes you could use `clsx` or `classnames` to conditionally apply them

```
import clsx from 'clsx'

const Component = () =>{
    const compoundStyle = clsx({
        [HeaderStyles] : true,
        [BulmaStyles] : true
    })

    return <div className={compoundStyle} />
}
```

You could also achieve the same result using `string interpolation`

```
const styles = `${styleA} ${styleB}`
return <div className={styles} />
```

Comment: thanks, you lead me to the right path, i change `{HeaderStyles.link}` to `${HeaderStyles.link}` and add the other class right after. so my 2 cent is className='${HeaderStyles.link} foo bar'